# Make all images on page draggable to a special upload field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, dropzone.js

I'm trying to write a browser extension that allows users to save pictures from page to favorites (like pinterest, you know). By clicking on the extension icon it adds a special field to html and user can drag any image from the page to it. Then the image uploaded to the server (preferably as a file, but simple url from `src="..."` may be usable too). See the example below.

Simple `input[type=file]` field does not respond to the page elements. I have tried [dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/), it works perfectly with local files, but does not work with page images (it responds, but chrome does not pass proper image object in the "drop" event).

Maybe there's some well-known ways to do it? Or existing JavaScript libraries? I don't really want to modify foreign page code, it may annoy users (for example use heavy jQuery UI and make all img tags draggable). Natural drag'n'drop behavior would be ideal.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the simple and beautiful solution.
Attach `onmousedown` event listener to every `img` tag on the page, save URL to temporary variable and read it if `ondrop` event fired on upload field.

Simplified example:

```
var imgURL = "";

$("a, img").on("mousedown", function(e) {
    var $target = $(e.target);
    if ($target.prop("tagName").toLowerCase() == 'img') {
        imgURL = $target.attr('src');
    }
});

$("#my-drop-area").on("dragenter dragover dragleave", function(e) {
    // need for proper ondrop event activation
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
}).on("drop", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.debug("Dropped! URL:", imgURL);
});
```